# how to get precise height for a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios

I am using SVGKit to draw a map, and it basically use SVG data to form a UIBezierPath, and pass it to CAShapeLayer and render it.

important code:

```
for (FSSVGPathElement* path in _svg.paths) {
    // Make the map fits inside the frame
    float scaleHorizontal = self.frame.size.width / _svg.bounds.size.width;
    float scaleVertical = self.frame.size.height / _svg.bounds.size.height;
    float scale = MIN(scaleHorizontal, scaleVertical);

    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
    scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(scaleTransform,-_svg.bounds.origin.x, -_svg.bounds.origin.y);

    UIBezierPath* scaled = [path.path copy];
    [scaled applyTransform:scaleTransform];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = scaled.CGPath;
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [_scaledPaths addObject:scaled];
}
```

The mapView's frame is set as the screen's width and height, and I found the map view's height is less than the screen height. So I want to cut the mapView's height to just same as the actual height of the map (UIBezierPah)

Because I don't know where to read the largest Y data for the UIBezierPath, I don't know how to calculate the max Y.

Can somebody help?

Comment: `Uibezierpath` has a bounds property, which you could use. Also [this](https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Advanced-Cookbook/tree/master/C04%20-%20Geometry/06%20-%20Fitting) might help you

Comment: could you speak more about the link you provided? Not sure what the purpose of the categories

Comment: There is a fitting category that fits the path within a given Rect, so it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bounds property for UIBezierPath, but what I am asking is the actual size of all the UIBeizerPath together.

I figured out with below code:

1. first add a property as the actual size,

`@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize actualSize;`

and When handling the UIBezierPath:

```
for (FSSVGPathElement* path in _svg.paths) {
    UIBezierPath* scaled = [path.path copy];
    [scaled applyTransform:scaleTransform];
    CGFloat absoluteWidth = scaled.bounds.origin.x + scaled.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat absoluteHeight = scaled.bounds.origin.y + scaled.bounds.size.height;
    if (absoluteHeight > maxHeight)
        maxHeight = absoluteHeight;
    if (absoluteWidth > maxWidth)
        maxWidth = absoluteWidth;
    ....
}

self.actualSize = CGSizeMake(ceil(maxWidth), ceil(maxHeight));
```

Now I can get the actual size after all paths are added into the CAShapeLayer.